# How can I add a text for a connection line just like the sample flow chart?

Tags: charts, diagrams

I use diagrams.net to create flow chart

I find a text *"No"* is added to a connection line in left sample flow chart, and the text can be moved automatically when I drag *"Plug in lamp"* icon, you can see Mark A.

I use text tool (Mark B) to add a text *"Yes"* for the connection line in right my flow chart, but the text is fixed, and it can not be moved automatically when I drag *"Sick"* icon ,you can see Mark C.

How can I add a text for a connection line just like the sample flow chart ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the connection, then start typing your text. That text will be linked to the connection. If you move the connection, the text will move with it.

Comment: Thanks! It's great